# Which programming pattern is preferred

Tags: design-patterns

If I have a class which all the functions in it need to pass a check first, which of the following is more preferred

1.

```
class check{
   public check(Status){
    if(CheckFunc(Status)){
       // Passed the Check function and return a class instance
       return new UpdateClass();
    }
}

class UpdateClass{
   public void Func1(){     
    // Do the stuff
   }
   // Other functions...
}
```

OR

2.

```
class UpdateClass{
    boolean passedCheck = false;
    public UpdateClass(Status){
        if(checkFunc(Status)){
            this.passedCheck = true;
        }
    }
    public void Func1(){
        if(this.passedCheck){
        // Do the stuff
        ...
        }
    }
    // Other functions...
}
```

Also, is it a good way to use a class/function to decide which class to be instantiated?

for example:

```
    public Animal decideWhichClass(Status){
        if(Status == StatusA){
            return new Dog();
        }
        else if (Status == StatusB){
        return new Cat();
        }
    }

    Animal a = decideWhichClass(CurrentStatus);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question) The check is a requirement for the update processing.
In the first way, you don't have this guarantee as `UpdateClass` may be created and used without passing the check.

The second one is so better as it prevent to bypass the check:

```
public UpdateClass(Status){
    if(checkFunc(Status)){
        this.passedCheck = true;
    }
}
```

> Also, is it a good way to use a class/function to decide which class
>   to be instantiated?

The example is broad but it is acceptable to have a `factory` of objects which the instantiated subclass depends on a specific parameter.
Note that to avoid `if/elseIf`, the function could rely on a Map structure.
Here is an example in Java (but you could get a similar thing in any Object language):

```
public class AnimalFactory{

   private static Map<Status, Supplier<Animal>> map = new HashMap<>();

   private AnimalFactory(){      
   }

   static {
     map.put(Status.A, Dog::new);
     map.put(Status.B, Cat::new);
   }

   public static Animal ofAnimal(Status status){ 
     return map.get(status).get(); 
     // of course you should also handle the error case : no association found
   }
}


 //Client code
Animal a = AnimalFactory.ofAnimal(Status.B);
```